# The same pattern works with chokidar-cli but does not work with chokidar on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, chokidar

Hello I'm trying to setup chokidar on Windows. I got to work it with `chokidar-cli`, this is the command line that reports the events correctly:

```
 chokidar "D:\PATH\**\WATCHED_FOLDER\*.TXT"
```

But when I try to do the same thing with `node index.js`, with the following code, the events don't get reported.

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
chokidar
    .watch('D:\\PATH\\**\\WATCHED_FOLDER\\*.TXT')
    .on('all', (event, path) => {
        console.log(event, path)
    })
```

I wonder why the same glob expression works on the command line and not in javascript. Also I did not find a reference on the syntax accepted by chokidar on Windows.

Can someone point out the problem here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `chokidar-cli` works with backslashes, `chokidar` requires forward slashes in the glob path. This works:

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
chokidar
    .watch('D:/PATH/**/WATCHED_FOLDER/*.TXT')
    .on('all', (event, path) => {
        console.log(event, path)
    })
```

But beware, the string in the variable `path` is in still with backslashes: e.g. `'D:\\PATH\\SUBFOLDER\\WATCHED_FOLDER\\TEST.TXT'`. This is somehow inconsistent, but it works.

Comment: Windows doesn't care about the slash direction due to an old Dos legacy style. Back when IBM ruled the world and before directories were a thing / was the way IBM used a switch. Windows uses   / for other things like running a command ie. `./httpd -k start apache2` due to the . in `./*CMD*` my hypothesis is that the left side is a Dir argument so windows doesn't need to worry about slash direction. Roll Tide